# I got error checkboxTrigger: execution of Afterinsert Record is read-only: Trigger.checkboxTrigger: line 5, column 1 plz help to get out of this

Tags: trigger

```
trigger checkboxTrigger on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    List<Id> acc= new List<Id>() ;

    for(Contact con: Trigger.new){
        if(con.Enable__c=true){
            acc.add(con.AccountId );   
        }
    }
   List<Contact> conlist=[Select MailingCity From Contact Where Id in : acc ];
   List<Account> acclist=[Select Name, BillingCity From Account Where Id in : acc ];
    for(integer i=0; i<acclist.size();i++ ){
       // if(acclist>0)
      String s= conlist[i].MailingCity;
       acclist[i].BillingCity=s;  
    // acclist[i].BillingCity=Contact.MailingCity;
    }
    try{
    update acclist;
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.getMessage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few changes in your code. You don't need two query here.

```
for(Contact con: Trigger.new){
        if(con.Enable__c){
            acc.add(con.AccountId );   
        }
    }
   List<Contact> conlist=[Select MailingCity, Account.BillingCity From Contact Where AccountId in : acc ];
  Map<Id, Account> accmap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(contact con : conlist){
        accmap.put(con.AccountId, new account(Id = con.AccountId, BillingCity = con.MailingCity));

    }
    try{
    update accmap.values();
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.getMessage();
}
}
```

Also keep in mind One account might have multiple contact in Which they will overwrite address.